# Show a initial dialog only if my App has been updated but not in new installs of my App

Tags: android

I want to show a dialog only when an user that has updated my app has init the app. I dont want that such dialog be showed if a user has made a new install of my app.

How can this be achieved?

I know that exists a BroadcastReceiver that listens to the ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED Intent but it does not match my needs.

I'm sure there is a different way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

When your activity is started, check for an app_version in shared preferences.  If it doesn't exist, the app is a new install-  don't show the dialog, just write the current version to shared preferences.  If it does exist, compare to the current version.  If its the same, ignore and move on.  If it isn't the same, show the dialog and write the new version number to shared preferences (so it doesn't show again).

Comment: app_version will not exists in my updates... so i dont know why this should work?

Comment: Because an updated app doesn't overwrite existing shared preferences.

Comment: what? i dont understand you.... my updated apps will write shared preferences value for the first time, like the new installs, because that shard preferences value does not exists in previous versions, so i cannot see the difference

Comment: If you have an app and update it, the old shared preferences are NOT deleted.  So if you had an old version (version 1) installed, you see that app_version=1.  When you upgrade to 2, then you'll check the value of app_version and see 1.  Since 1 != 2, you would show the dialog.

Comment: ¿?¿?¿?¿?¿ my currently installed apps does not have any app_version value stored in shared preferences!!! so all of them will count as new installs with your method. Did you understand it now?

Comment: Then you should have shown more foresight and added this behavior in v1, and specified that you need that in your question.  But the answer is still the same-  you use this method for the steady state, then special case for the old ones-  look for any shared preference, file, or other internal piece of state your app creates.  If it already exists, it is not a new install.  So if it looks like a new install but has some pre-existing piece of data saved, its an upgrade.